# Интенсивное использование диска. Ubuntu server 16

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, vps

Добрый день. 
На vps тестируется веб-скрейпер, пришло сообщение от хостера, что диск используется слишком интенсивно и могут заблокировать сервер.

[image: График использования диска]

Всего сервер имеет 512 МБ ОЗУ.

Данные парсер хранит в оперативной памяти - массив строк из ~20(на данный момент) тысяч элементов, каждая строка ~15 символов, т.е. всего 16*15*20 000 = ~4.8 МБайта.
Также пишет логи на диск, за ~20 часов "исписал" ~14 МБайт.

Как понимаю: утечки памяти -> интенсивное использование свопа.

Смотрите процессы node и phantomjs столбец virt.

[image: Процессы node и phantomjs столбец virt]

Можно как-нибудь не останавливая процесс, уменьшить интенсивность использования диска?

Comment: Можете попробовать выключить своп.. Но нода скорее всего упадёт..

Comment: Вы излишне оптимистично оцениваете объём памяти под строки. Это вам не Си

Comment: Оу, там ещё и фантом?  Покупайте больше памяти

Comment: @AlexeyTen в JS строки хранятся в формате UTF-16 - каждый символ по 16 бит

Comment: Тогда вы умножаете что-то странное. 16 бит это два байта. Итого примерно 600Кб. Но вы почему-то не учитываете, что строки это не набор байт, а объекты. А также, что это наверное самое маленькое что у вас есть.  Вы же скачиваете кучу информации и она тоже где-то должна храниться

Comment: @AlexeyTen вы правы, я ошибся при подсчетах.